# Detect fullscreen mode in vscode extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

There seems to a command to toggle fullscreen mode `workbench.action.toggleFullScreen` but I could not find any way to detect whether the window is in fullscreen mode or not.

Is there any way(that I missed), or a workaround(some non-trivial way) to get this information?